# Specific Validation on a reusable code inputs

Tags: python, function, validation, input

Assignment:
My assignment is to make a simple program that solves a specific formula. there are three inputs x y and n and these three inputs must use the same reusable code

Problem:
while using a reusable code the teacher want me to validate a single variable in the code which is "n" must be greater than 0

Code:

```
import math
def main():
    x = inputdata()
    y = inputdata()
    n = inputdata()
    n = validate(n)
    fact = myfactorial(n)
    A = solveA(x,n,fact)
    B = solveB(A,x,y,n)
    show(A,B)
def inputdata():
    z = int (input('Enter the Value \n Value = '))
    z = validate(z)
    return z
def solveA(x,n,fact):
    A = ((x**n) / fact)
    return A
def solveB(A,x,y,n):
    B = ((2*A*x) + math.acos((0.235*n)))/((y**3)**(1/7))
    return B
def myfactorial(n):
    fact = 1
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        fact = fact * i
    return fact
def show(A,B):
    print("The value of A {:1.4f}".format(A))
    print("The value of B {:1.4f}".format(B))
def validate(Value):
    while Value < 0:
        print("Invalid input, enter again : ")
        Value=int(input())
    return Value

x="Y"
while(x!="N"):
    main()
    x=input("Press Y to continue, N to stop : ").upper()
```

'bug':
it is validating all of the variables including x y and n even though i just want it to validate n

```
  Enter the Value 
 Value = -2
Invalid input, enter again : 
2
Enter the Value 
 Value = -2
Invalid input, enter again : 
2
Enter the Value 
 Value = 2
The value of A 2.0000
The value of B 6.7475
Press Y to continue, N to stop :
```

Comment: Because `inputdata()` calls `validate()`. Don't do that.

Comment: isn't that how you should validate inputs? or should i put it in the main()?

Comment: But you said you don't want to validate all inputs. You call `validate(n)` in `main()`, you don't need to do it in both places.

Comment: Thank you I removed the validate() in input data just as you said and it worked ^_^

HONESTLY WHY CAN'T UNDERSTAND SUCH A SIMPLE MISTAKE

THANK YOU GOOD SIR FOR HELPING ME